# Oven wont turn back on after turning off circuit breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, oven

I accidentally flipped the oven circuit breaker in my electric panel to 'OFF' while baking (was fixing a separate electrical problem), and now my oven won't turn back on (no clock or anything), even after I flip the circuit breaker back to 'ON'. Before I rip the oven out of the wall to check for blown fuse boxes, any ideas on what I should try? Do I have to wait awhile before turning the circuit breaker back to 'ON'?

Update: managed to access the control board. The fuse looks fine, so I'm not sure it was a power surge that killed the board.

[image]

Comment: What make/model is said oven?

Comment: Whirlpool RBD305PDQ1 http://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-number/rbd305pdq1/1198/0125300.html

Comment: The oven is on its own circuit I take it? Or does it share a circuit with another oven, a cooktop, etc?

Comment: It's on it's own circuit. There are 2 ovens using the same power source, and I was using the lower one. I tested the circuit breaker with a multimeter, and it's not an issue with the breaker itself. I'm not sure why the oven would break from an accidental cut to power when it's in operation. Could it be a thermal fuse tripping? (but it was actually already cooling down when I cut the power).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a sign that turning the power back on did the control board in -- inrush often can send a marginal component to its grave.  I'd check for power to the control board -- if it's getting power, then it's toast and needs to be replaced.

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply. I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as I verify that is the case.

Comment: just to clarify - there is a voltage across the ground and thermal fuse, which seems to imply that the fuse is fine and the board is getting power. If the fuse is OK, how did the board get fried?

Comment: @ejang -- could be a latent manufacturing defect or a component that's worn out, tired, and ready to head home...

Comment: But wait,,, Resistors don't have inrush.

Comment: @Harper -- the heating elements don't, but the control board sure does

Comment: The controllers (often called 'timers') must be a weak point in these ovens as they are in ranges, clothes washers and dryers. One can source a new one or a rebuilt one. I couldn't get a new or rebuilt one for our 20-year-old GE range so I sent mine in for repair. It has worked fine for 5 years since. Total cost $126.

Comment: I used https://www.appliancetimers.com/appliance?model=rbd305pdq14 four years ago (not 5). Their list has an extra digit on the model number from the one given by the questioner.